# Prevent .deb package from substituting system icons

Tags: apt, package-management, icons, deb

I have installed [Softmaker Office](https://www.softmaker.com/it/softmaker-office) but its .deb installer has entered in every `/usr/share/icons/*` directory substituting the icons for .docx/.xlsx/.pptx files with its own icons.

If I uninstall it, the icons turn back to the normal ones for the respective theme.

How can I prevent a .deb package to do that when it is installed?

Comment: Install it, then delete non needed icons.

Comment: By the way, you can check list from: `dpkg -L softmaker-office-2021 | grep icons`